# Running react native iOS simulator on another local machine

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, metro-bundler

I am running my react native expo app on my windows machine, and the expo devtool is running on local:19002. When I tried to access the devtool on my macbook going to "my-windows-machines-ip":19002 it just doesn't responds. Not sure what I am doing wrong here. When I go to 19001 though. it displays this message 'React Native packager is running' on the macbook browser.

What I am trying to do is running the iOS simulator on my macbook, while running the app on my Windows machine.

Comment: Can you double check that node is allowed incoming connections in the macOS firewall under "Security & Privacy"?  That's what I would check is blocking the connection first.

Comment: @zero298 yeah I added there, and also tried it firewall off, didn't help.